# Where am I making a mistake in my evaluation of $A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{1.96}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{1.96}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx$$

The following webpage gives this expression and states that ''after integration this yields a value of 0.024998''.

https://statcalc.weebly.com/z-scores-and-probability-distribution.html

I can't figure out how this value was obtained.

I tried squaring the expression and using a double integral but I must be using the wrong limits as I'm not getting the same value.

$$A^2=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{1.96}^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\frac{-r^2}{2}}r\ dr\ d\theta$$

$$A^2=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\frac{1.96^2}{2}}^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-u}\ du\ d\theta$$

$$A^2=e^{-1.9208}$$

$$A=0.3827$$

Did I make a mistake along the way or am I using the wrong limits?

I can add more of my steps if necessary.

Comment: You didn't change your limits in the $u$ substitution step, but also given the integration domain, polar coordinates is not going to be the best thing to use. Your polar bounds will not go all the way around, they would go from $r = 1.96\csc\theta$ to $r = 1.96\sec\theta$.

Comment: After your trick of squaring the domain of integration is a (infinite) square. But you integrated over an infinite annulus

Comment: @NinadMunshi How did you get those new limits of $r=1.96\csc\theta$ and $r=1.96\sec\theta$ ?

Comment: You can't fit a square peg into a round hole.

Answer (score 2):

You did not render the volume in the two-dimensional integral properly.  Given any integrable function $f$, we can render

$(\int_a^bf(x) dx)^2$

as the volume between the product $f(x)f(y)$ and the $xy$ plane over a square region of the latter.  But **you can't convert the square into an annulus or a disk (by using polar coordinates) unless you push the boundaries to infinity.**

So integrating $e^{-x^2}dx$ by your double integral method gives a nice result when the limits are $\pm\infty$ but not with any other set of limits.

There are many ways to properly approximate the error function.  I will not reiterate them here, instead referring to [this WP article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: I had a feeling that would be a problem. Any suggestions of an alternative method ?

Comment: There may be something you can do with asymptotuc analysis, but I have not looked closely at it.

Comment: It's not an elementary integral, Kantura. It can only be evaluated numerically.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Now that you mention it, I've seen that statement somewhere before ''It can only be evaluated numerically''. I have no idea what that means. How does one evaluate numerically?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Does it mean like the Simpsons rule etc ?

Comment: @Kantura Yes. Using Simpson's rule, or tanh-sinh quadrature, midpoint rule, Gauss-Laguerre quadrature, etc. There are many methods.

Comment: What @K.defaoite said. Although as you have an integral to infinity, with at least some of those methods you're going to have to split it into an integral to some large $x_0$, and then an integral from $x_0$ to infinity, and on that second integral, use some kind of estimate of the integrand.

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of [$\operatorname{erf}$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html) -
$$\int \exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+C$$
So we want to compute
$$A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\bigg[\lim_{x\to\infty }\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{1.96}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\bigg]$$
$$A=\frac{1}{2}(1-0.9500042097...)\approx 0.0249978951...$$

However, as stated by others, $\operatorname{erf}$ is non-elementary.